# Displaying Array Using Smarty Template?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to use Smarty to automatically insert data into a `textarea`.

There are two lines that will be inserted.  Here's an example of what would be inserted:

```
John Doe
Level 1, Support Tech
```

Obviously each name would have a position associated with it.

I'm imagining it should be something like this:

```
$array-names = array("John Joe", "Jane Doe", "Random Name");
$array-positions = array("Level 1, Support Tech", "Level 2, Sales Staff", "Level 2, Billing Team");
```

And then I would just need to randomly pick one to automatically insert - but they need to match. For example, `John Doe` should always have `Level 1, Support Tech` listed below.

Is doing something like this possible in Smarty or am I on the totally wrong track...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you create an array in Smarty in the order you described

Then use this following method in smarty to display the array, for example:

```
<?php
//an organized array with names and positions that match
$array_names_positions = array(1 => array('Name' => 'John Doe', 'position' => 'Level 1, Support Tech'),
                              2 => array('Name' => 'Jane Doe', 'position' => 'Level 2, Sales Staff')
                              3 => array('Name' => 'Random Name', 'position' => 'Level 2, Billing Team')
                    );

//assign the array to $items var
$smarty->assign('items', $array_names_positions);

//draw a textarea and display the array, (you can work on your display mechanism to limit or to display all here
<textarea>
{foreach from=$items key=myId item=i}
  {$i.name}: {$i.position}
{/foreach}
</textarea>
```

When you say randomly pick one to automatically insert, you can either randomly display one in the textarea and have a submit button to save that record to db.

And if you want to randomize you can use 
$array_names_positions[mt_rand(0,count($array_names_positions)-1)] 
to shuffle

You can put the php code in the .tpl file; becareful when you insert php code in a smarty template file. Be sure to use:

```
{php}
//php code here
{/php}
```

in your smarty template. Don't mix too much php code with the template file; it defeats the purpose of the template to keep it balanced. If the php code has ton of logic you should put that in a smarty controller.

Comment: That looks almost exactly what I'm looking for, but it looks like it requires it to be entered in the .php file, whereas I only have access to Smarty's (.tpl) template files.  Could it be modified to work in the .tpl because that's exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You could generande `rand(0, count($array-names)-1)` in php, pass it to smarty and use it as key for the arrays in Smarty.

Comment: I actually though about doing that, the problem is that the PHP file that's associated with the smarty template is encrypted so I can't make any changes to it :(

Comment: Generate the random in the smarty then. `{math equation='rand(0,count(array-names))' assign='selection'} `